# Reducing countable collections of countably infinite sets to pairwise disjoint sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This might be obvious (or not); but I want to know if it is true that if $\{X_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a collection of countably infinite sets, then there exists $\{Y_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, pairwise disjoint, such that each $Y_i$ is an infinite subset of $X_i$.

Comment: You are right; it is a duplicate of a question that I was not able to find via search. Thanks.

Comment: Trevor's solution is nice. Hope you find it useful.